# Trouble when storing API data in Python list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm struggling with my json data that I get from an API. I've gone into several api urls to grab my data, and I've stored it in an empty list. I then want to take out all fields that say "reputation" and I'm only interested in that number. See my code here:

```
import json
import requests

f = requests.get('my_api_url')
if(f.ok):
    data = json.loads(f.content)

url_list = [] #the list stores a number of urls that I want to request data from

for items in data:
    url_list.append(items['details_url']) #grab the urls that I want to enter

total_url = [] #stores all data from all urls here   

for index in range(len(url_list)):
    url = requests.get(url_list[index])
    if(url.ok):
    url_data = json.loads(url.content)
    total_url.append(url_data)

print(json.dumps(total_url, indent=2)) #only want to see if it's working
```

Thus far I'm happy and can enter all urls and get the data. It's in the next step I get trouble. The above code outputs the following json data for me:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 316,
      "name": "storabro",
      "url": "https://storabro.net",
      "customer": true,
      "administrator": false,
      "reputation": 568
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 541,          
      "name": "sega",
      "url": "https://wedonthaveanyyet.com",
      "customer": true,
      "administrator": false,
      "reputation": 45
    },
    {
      "id": 90,
      "name": "Villa",
      "url": "https://brandvillas.co.uk",
      "customer": true,
      "administrator": false,
      "reputation": 6
    }
  ]
]
```

However, I only want to print out the **reputation**, and I cannot get it working. If I in my code instead use `print(total_url['reputation'])` it doesn't work and says `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"`, and if I try:

`for s in total_url:
print(s['reputation'])`
I get the same TypeError.

Feels like I've tried everything but I can't find any answers on the web that can help me, but I understand I still have a lot to learn and that my error will be obvious to some people here. It seems very similar to other things I've done with Python, but this time I'm stuck. To clarify, I'm expecting an output similar to: `[568, 45, 6]`

Perhaps I used the wrong way to do this from the beginning and that's why it's not working all the way for me. Started to code with Python in October and it's still very new to me but I want to learn. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: As you iterate over your data structure, `total_url` will have a *list* as `s`, lists are indexed with *integers*. As the error messages plainly state, `total_url['reputation']` will not work because you cannot index a list with a string. Try just `print`ing `total_url`, and you'll see, they are lists with a single element (probably not very useful lists)

Comment: So, if your api call always returns a list of object, just use `total_url.extend(...)` instead of `total_url.append`

Comment: Ah, you do realise that requests also includes a [JSON
decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).
So you could skip importing `json` and just use `data = f.json()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this! Didn't know `.extend` was an option and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `total_url` is a list of lists, so you might write a function like:

```
def get_reputations(data):
    for url in data:
        for obj in url:
            print(obj.get('reputation'))

get_reputations(total_url)

# output:
# 568
# 45
# 6
```

If you'd rather not work with a list of lists in the first place, you can `extend` the list with each result instead of `append` in the expression used to construct `total_url`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use json.load and try to read the response

```
def get_rep():
response = urlopen(api_url)
r = response.read().decode('utf-8')
r_obj = json.loads(r)
for item in r_obj['response']:
    print("Reputation: {}".format(item['reputation']))
```